# What is retagging exactly?

Tags: support, edits, badges, terminology

I was looking for ways to achieve badges, and I stumbled upon the Organiser badge. The description said, "First Retag". I didn't know what a retag was, so naturally, I looked it up on meta. But the search results were about misusage of retags if a retag reject was correct, but nothing about *what a retag actually was!* I looked at the help center, but surprisingly, it wasn't helpful either! Can someone please tell me what a retag is? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To "retag" is to add, remove, and/or change the tag(s) on a question.

It's as simple as that.

Retagging is one of the actions that can be taken while submitting an edit to a question. Other actions include changing the title (re-titling?), editing the body, etc. Anyone can submit edits, including anonymous users, so anyone can retag a question and earn the badge, assuming that their edits are approved.

If you look at [the users who have recently earned the Organizer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer), you're linked to the question that earned them the badge. Looking at the revision history will show you what edits they made. [frederic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14909980/frederic) recently earned the Organizer badge by adding a tag to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65637643/revisions), without making any other changes. [altz3r0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14969285/altz3r0) recently earned the Organizer badge by adding a tag *and* making other edits to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65637366/revisions). Any modifications to the tags would count for earning the badge.

Comment: *editing the body* -> re-bodying